# Only handling pyside6 input when entry is complete

Tags: focus, pyside6, v-debounce

What I mean by complete is that most signals for say a QLineEdit based widget are character by character.  I only want to handle the input when the user is finished entering the text. I have seen a debounce way using a QTimer kicked off by the original signal but that it seems to me starts a new timer for every character.
I see there are events for catching focus change and handlers for those that I might subclass in my own custom widget classes to emit a custom signal which I then handle.  Is this the best way?
What is considered best practice for this?

Comment: [`QLineEdit.editingFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished).

Comment: thanks!   That will do nicely.